# Is there a way to resize a web browser's window so that their dimesions are a specific width and height?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I need to view a webpage using specific dimensions without having to resize a web browser window all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Windows)

**Firefox:**

- Shortcut: **Ctrl+Shift+M**, or:
- Press F12 to open devtools sidebar
- On the top right corner of the bar, click the button "Responsive Design-modus", the icon looks like a little phone on a tablet

**Chrome/ Edge:**

- Shortcut: **Ctrl+Shift+M**, or:
- Press F12 to open devtools sidebar
- On top left corner of the bar, click the button "Toggle device toolbar", the icon looks like a phone on a tablet (Chrome) or a phone on a screen (Edge)

**Opera:**

- Shortcut: **Ctrl+Shift+M** (might not work and open Messenger sidebar by default), or:
- Press Ctrl+Shift+I to open devtools sidebar
- On top left corner of the bar, click the button "Toggle device toolbar", the icon looks like a phone on a tablet

**How to use:**

- From the dropdown menu "Responsive" you can change the viewport size to match a set of devices or add your own, or leave it on responsive and change the two number fields next to it with the desired width and height